# pocket hole joint Vs. cam lock joint - What's sturdier?

Tags: wood, joinery, plywood, fasteners

what is the strongest joint between using such fasteners https://www.core77.com/posts/27725/Death-to-Cam-Lock-Nuts-Flatpack-Hardware-That-Will-Hopefully-Become-Obsolete (ikea furniture ones), and the kreg screws for pocket holes ?

Using a 90 angle joint between a vertical and horizontal panels, is there a winner resisting better to both: a pullout of the horizontal panel in the vertical direction, a push to the left/right of the vertical pannel (in a tangent/horizontal direction) ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. There's a clear winner here in terms of strength, but these are not really equivalent fastening options, with one being take-downable (and within reason, indefinitely so) and the other typically not, so is there a specific reason for you wanting a comparison between them? There are of course numerous other ways to join two boards/panels at 90°! Many of the others also surpass the cam locks for security, but again at the cost of not creating a knock-down join.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that not all knock-down fasteners are created equal.  Even for cam lock connectors there is a huge difference between well-made hardware with tight tolerances and the cheap ones you find in most budget furniture.  Also, knock-down hardware gets a bad reputation because it's typically used in particle board, which doesn't hold any kind of fastener very well.  In hardwood or a quality plywood knock-down connectors can be "strong enough" for most uses.

Comment: Also, you tagged the question with "plywood", but nowhere do you actually state that you're using these in plywood.  This does make a difference, as pocket holes will be weaker and cam-locks stronger in solid wood due to the surface area of end-grain that would pull out in a failure.  (I.e. pulling the screw head out vs the whole barrel of the cam-lock.)

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, I'm not sure if the cheap cams are inherently bad because of their cheapness, as long as they are capable of tightening on to the rod/bolt that intersects with them (obviously not a given, but IME they do tend to do this pretty reliably). What I have seen a lot with cheaper furniture — I'm looking at you Ikea — is the holes drilled for the cams are hardly what you'd call uniform! Just like with the dowel holes, the very inconsistent drilling by itself does a lot to undermine the potential for initial rigidity and long-term tightness.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of clarification from the OP I'll Answer this with a given set of assumptions.

The basic answer here is pocket-hole screws, and by a pretty large margin.

It's not simply that the screws themselves are so much more secure than a steel rod of some kind intersecting with a cam<sup>1</sup>, it's that **pocket-hole screws tend not to be used in isolation**. The norm for screw installation in pocket holes (and actually much assembly of furniture using screws) is to both **glue and screw**. And the glued joint does *a lot* of the heavy lifting when it comes to joint strength, particularly so in solid wood which edge-glues far more strongly than plywood does.

In addition to outright strength, there's the issue of flex and other movement in a joint. A joint that can shift even slightly is always at risk of becoming looser over time if it's stressed, but even from normal day-to-day loads being applied (minor stuff, like leaning forward into the surface of a desk as you work at it), as well as from seasonal wood movement<sup>2</sup>.

And this is precisely why screws are rarely used by themselves in quality furniture work; not necessarily high-end stuff, just anything intended to last. Because they allow for *some* movement they tend to wallow out their own holes and you enter into a cycle of damage — movement leads to wallowing which allows for even more movement, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least in a fresh installation, where everything is done well.

<sup>2</sup> So just sitting there unused something can become a little less tight and solid than when it was last used.